# 14.04.2, 15.04 Boot Problems

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

I have been attempting to install 14.04.2 on a machine that previously ran 14.04 without issues.

I can go through installation, install/remove a few packages (removed all non-essential software, installed SSH Server, Chrome and Dropbox-Nautilius).

However, sooner or later, after a reboot, my machine will end up booting into a blank, black, yet lit up screen.

I have reinstalled Lubuntu around 5 times now, eventually, the result is the same. I cannot pinpoint a specific action that leads to this behaviour, but something tells me that there's an issue with the newer versions of the Kernel.

I have provided the boot log [here](http://luxembourgdesign.com/bootlog.txt).